# MS-Access 2013 Web Apps - Why does GoToRecord break when the view contains a subview?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a view that has next/previous buttons that allow the user to navigate to the next records, using a GoToRecord macro. When there is no subview, when the user gets to the final record, and then presses Next, they receive an error stating they have gone past the last record and then the view returns to normal (that is, the next/previous controls work).

However, when I add in the subview and the user goes past the last record using the Next button, they receive the same error but the view controls become inactive (that is, the next/previous controls do not work). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a product issue to me. I work with the Access product team and when I try out your steps on my test machine, I wasn't able to repro your specific issue unless my focus was in the subview. In that scenario, further clicks on the main view's custom Next/Previous action bar buttons seem to get swallowed. If I then click say the Edit button on the main view action bar, then all of my previous "swallowed" actions all happen in quick succession.

Is that the behavior you are seeing? If so, this is most likely a product bug in which case there is no way for you to work around the issue. I have discussed this issue with the Access product team and they will be investigating it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will update this issue soon. Alternatively, do you have a point of contact?