# Access 2013 Web App - Why when subview data isn't saved and try to navigate to next record, Access disables controls?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a List view (parent), and inside of that I have a sub view that is a blank view which contains some input boxes. I also have Next/Previous buttons in the parent that use GoToRecord to navigate to the next/previous records.

If I enter some data into the subview and try to navigate away using the Next/Previous buttons, I recieve an error asking me to Save, Discard or Edit my inputs in the subview (which is fine). However, if I:

- click Save: It goes to the next record (expected) but the controls on the next record do not work
- click Discard: Same as above - that is, it goes to the next record but none of the controls work
- click Continue Editing: It jumps to the next record and populates the subview with the data from the previous record.

Why am I encountering these issues? Is this a product issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this seems to be a product issue. I believe this is essentially the same type of underlying product issue you identified in your earlier post here:

[MS-Access 2013 Web Apps - Why does GoToRecord break when the view contains a subview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457916/ms-access-2013-web-apps-why-does-gotorecord-break-when-the-view-contains-a-sub)

I talked with the product team and they are looking into this. Access seems to be swallowing the custom Action Bar buttons in this scenario with a main and Subview.